# Swift adding image icons to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was trying to import separate image icons next to my tableview cells  using this code

```
switch(Anime)   {
    case 0:       
        var bleachimage = UIImage(named: "bleach icon")
        cell.imageView?.image  = bleachimage
    }
```

But I keep getting an error marked at `case 0` saying `type int does not conform to protocol IntervalType`.

I'm using Swift by the way with Xcode 6.1

I also read before posting this that I was supposed to be switching the cell index not the array, I tried it and failed so maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Thx for the help.

Comment: Error log should be clear enough. Anime is not an Int. So what exactly is Anime? Where does it come from at what do you want to accomplish with Anime? Show more code

Comment: Anime is an array of tuples with a name of a certain anime and its writer  i was trying to use the switch statement to import different images for every cell

Comment: the images are supposed to be next to the cell title by the way

Comment: If the code is inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you should switch through the indexPath, i.e. `switch(indexPath.row) {}` - based on the current row you can decide which image you want to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

1. Your array `anime` (yes it's `Anime` but you should use the lowercase for the first char) has `n` elements where `n` is the number of the cells in your table
2. Each element of `anime` is a `tuple`
3. The first element of the `tuple` (declared at bullet 2) is a `String` representing the name of the image **locally stored**

You can add an image to each cell with this code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as? UITableViewCell
        ?? UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")
    let tuple = self.anime[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: tuple.0)
    return cell
}
```

Hope this helps.

### Update to better answer the comment

The method above is called by iOS for every cell that needs to be displayed. Each time it is called with an `indexPath` referring a specific cell.

> E.g. if iOS need to display cell `0` in section `0` (the first cell in
>   your table) the `indexPath` will have the `row` property equals to `0` and
>   `section` equals to `0`. For cell `1` in section `0`, the index path will have
>   `row` equals to `1` and `section` equals to `0`. And so on...

So, what I am doing inside this method? I am accessing the element `indexPath.row` of array `anime`, in order to retrieve the `tuple` needed to populate the cell at position `indexPath.row`.
Next I extract the first element of the tuple (a string containing the name of the image) and I use that value to build a `UIImage`.
Next I assign that image to the current cell. Finally I return the cell.

Just try it. If the assumptions are correct, it will work.

Comment: thx a bunch but what i really wanted was to put one image for a single cell your code adds the same image to all cells

Comment: Actually my code does exactly what you need. It extracts the image name from the **first cell of the array** and does assign it to the **first cell of the table**. The second image in the array goes in the second cell and so on...

Comment: I'm sorry for asking this but I'm new to the programming experience but from i can understand from your code is that you extract the first tuple name but what about the image itself

Comment: No problem. We are here to learn. Tomorrow morning I will provide you more explainations about my code.

Comment: Ok, I added a new section to my answer.

Comment: Perfect, If you think my answer is correct please accept it.

Comment: can u help me out with something else i posted the question as an answer in this forum but it seems u added the same answer what i want is when i tap the cell a certain image appears I've already added the icons to the cell using the code you gave me

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look tomorrow!